# how to change object property?

Tags: javascript, object

I'm struggling updating an object property. I haven't encounter one like that before.

How can I update the duration property?!

```
var test = new ProgressBar.Circle('#circus', {
  strokeWidth: 3,
  duration: 60000,
  color: '#21abe9',
  trailColor: '#f4f4f4',
  trailWidth: 1,
  svgStyle: null,
});
```

test.duration = 5 for example, won't do anything.

Thank you!

Comment: I'd suggest start with `console.dir(test)`. That object is most likely not  what you think it is.

Comment: It looks like you're using a JavaScript package of some sort. Where is `ProgressBar.Circle` from?

Comment: from ProgressBar.js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing that you are using [ProgressBar.js](https://kimmobrunfeldt.github.io/progressbar.js/) library. According to its [API](http://progressbarjs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/shape/) you have two options:

- Override `duration` by passing new value as optional options to `.animate()` call:

  ```
  test.animate(0.5, {
      duration: 1000 // new value
  });
  ```
- Create new ProgressBar with correct parameters

Comment: Thank you! I was driving myself crazy since hours!!

Comment: I tried the same type of syntax to change the color, but no luck... any clue?